# Permalink for Homepage

Tags: wordpress

I have a simple wordpress question. Currently I have a site with a static home page, when I visit my site examplesite.com the URL reads what it should which is examplesite.com, would it be possible to give this static home page a permalink so that when I load the site it automatically turns to examplesite.com/customlink. What I am saying is I still want the same home page and the same URL to reach it, I just want a specific permalink to appear. I can edit permalinks for all other pages but since this is my homepage I see no option to do it automatically in wordpress.

Comment: go to your admin >settings>general>reading>Front page displays and set your page to deafult

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with PHP, it should be migrated to [WordPress Development Stack Exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) if possible.

Comment: @RakeshSharma I'm sorry that doesn't answer my question. I already have my home page set as default. The issue is a cannot get a permalink to appear in the window

Comment: Did you found a way to do this? I need the same thing and can´t find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Inside settings you can set static pages as default.

Comment: I'm sorry that doesn't answer my question. I already have my home page set as default. The issue is a cannot get a permalink to appear in the window

Answer (score 0):

For this you'll need `.htaccess`, e.g.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ page-you-want [L,R=301]
```

So any requests to root will get moved to the permalink you want. You don't need to set your home page to a static page/front page.

Comment: If possible (if you have access) you should always prefer redirection inside the server configuration to using .htaccess style files. Those files slow down the server a considerable amount, they are hard to debug and error prone. They should be last ressort.